# Bidirectional Binding with double to double converter in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, binding, converters

I bind the translateX-Property of Node b to translateX-Property of Node a:

```
b.translateXProperty().bindBidirectional(a.translateXProperty());
```

But now I want to add an offset, that b's translateX is shifted. I'm used to WPF's mechanism where I simply implement a subclass of `IValueConverter` and give it to the Binding. But how to do this in JavaFX? I found StringConverter that seems to be the equivalent. But it exists only for StringProperties and converts from/to strings.

How to use converters in a more generic way like in WPF?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : `b.translateXProperty().bindBidirectional(a.translateXProperty().add(offset));` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha That won't compile: `bindBidirectional` takes a `Property<Number>`, but the return type from `add` is a `DoubleBinding`. (The underlying problem is that the binding doesn't automatically know how to "undo" the `add` function.)

Comment: Do you need a bidirectional binding here? Or will a one-way binding be enough? If you need a bidirectional binding there is no way to do that with bindings in the standard API: you would need two listeners. (There is a way with bindings using the [ReactFX framework](http://www.reactfx.org).)

Comment: @James_D Ah, my bad! I missed the *bidirectional* ;)

Comment: @0xDEADBEEF Have you found a solution for this problem? I am struggling with the same problem